# event Listener close browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events

I want to have an event listener when just close browser. The event listener `unload` and `beforeUnload` also happen when referesh browsering and close browser run. I want it to run just when closing the browser.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  // // move userData to Context-API ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  const userDataStorage = JSON.parse(window.sessionStorage.getItem('userData')) || JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('userData'));
  if (userDataStorage) {
    changeUserData(ACTION_TYPE.PATCH_DATA, { ...userDataStorage
    });
    // window.localStorage.setItem('userData', JSON.stringify(userDataStorage)); // for login in new tab browser
    // window.sessionStorage.setItem('userData', JSON.stringify(userDataStorage)); // for login in new tab browser
  }

  const beforeUnloadBrowser = () => {
    window.localStorage.removeItem('userData');
    if (!userData.isRemember) {
      // when Refresh Browser localStorage clear but sessionStorage Save Data
      // when Close Browser sessionStorage auto cleat and if isRemember false localStorage clear
    }
  };
  window.addEventListener('bef', beforeUnloadBrowser);

  // update Time ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  const elementDay = elementDate.current.children[0];
  const elementTime = elementDate.current.children[1];

  const updateTime = () => {
    const date = new persianDate(new Date());
    elementDay.innerText = date.format('dddd');
    elementTime.innerText = date.format('HH:mm:ss');
  };
  const timer = window.setInterval(updateTime, 1000);

  // Function Cleanup //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  return () => {
    window.clearTimeout(timer);
    // window.removeEventListener('close', beforeUnloadBrowser);
  };
}, []);
```

Comment: This is not possible. All you can do is detect when the page is unloaded, which also fires on navigation events.